Can we get a description for the [ole] tag?
Could we ask for the description of the ole tag or its removal?
I used the tag in the sense of Object Linking and Embedding in How to compare TIFF files with tags 37680 (0x9330)?, but see http://merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ole and dozens of other possibilities in http://acronymfinder.com/Information-Technology/OLE.html and http://abbreviations.com/OLE.

Tag description added.

@DavidPostill Can I request a further disambiguation by renaming the tag? Something like [tag:microsoft-ole] or [tag:object-linking-and-embedding], keeping ole as a synonym.

@Robotnik All done
